# End User License Agreement (EULA) for products submitted by Publishers to the Autodesk App Store?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm about to publish my product at the App Store. Where do I find the EULA for products submitted by Publishers to the Autodesk Store? I want to see the EULA for a published product in the Autodesk App Store before I publish it. Do you recommend to change it for your product? What parts of the EULA are the most important? How do I refer to the EULA once I've published my product?